# Analog mixer design help choosing between 2 states

Tags: voltage, analog, mixer

I have designed 2 types of mixer an additive and a substractive one:

The additive one is a practical application of Millman's theorem connected to an opamp:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgU7N8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And the substractive is a voltage substractor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRA2aG.png)</sup>

I want to have a mechanical switch which will choose which type i will use every time.How to do that?

I want to drive loads of feedback(which will go to the input of the transistor).

I am recently interested in circuits with feedback and I run this circuit on LTSpice:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgVn4e.png)</sup>

that is why I am asking this.

Comment: You have a differential output voltage in the 2nd case and a single-ended output voltage in the first case. The latter is able to drive milliamp loads, the former isn't. Your question isn't confusing, so far as it goes. You want a mechanical switch idea. Got it. Sadly, I have no real idea about what the output is supposed to actually be/drive/etc and I can't push these two ideas into one. Not as they are, anyway. So I'll just be confused, I guess.

Comment: Okay maybe I will edit to make both single-ended.